# onActivityResult RESULT_OK can not be resolved to a variable in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to launch camera in fragment but onActivityResult in fragment doesn't resolve RESULT_OK. What should i do?

I am launching camera using:

```
public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1999;

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

get captured image using:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        if (bitmap != null) {
        }
    }
}
```

and i want captured image in current fragment!

Answer (score 172, accepted):

*[RESULT_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) is constant of Activity class. In Activity class you can access directly but in other classes you need to write class name (Activity) also.*

Use `Activity.RESULT_OK` instead of RESULT_OK.

---

In your case it will be

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
```

Answer (score 6):

In fragment we must use `getActivity()` method as prefix with `RESULT_OK`.

In your case it will be:-

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK)
```

Comment: I got warning "Static member 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.RESULT_OK' accessed via instance reference", seamless with Activity.RESULT_OK

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can add `import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;` and use it in your case like `if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {..}`