# Fail to sign in to Google Play Game

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've been having problem with signing into Google Play Game services
Getting

```
connectionResult.getErrorCode() == 4
```

And onActivityResult

```
resultCode == 1002
```

I can't figure out where the error comes from, I walked through all Google walkthroughs and checked every questions on Stack Overflow also went over the SHA1 code also application ID. 
Maybe someone can help me spot the problem or the missing part.

[GitHub](https://github.com/oriamd/TreasureHunt)

Comment: [Error 4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28450324/5832311) means that you have problem with sign in and you have not configured consent screen correctly. From this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263974), add a `Product Name` in `Google API console` > `Consent screen`. Also, based from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23085145/5832311), try to use `Activity.RESULT_OK` instead of `RESULT_OK`. `RESULT_OK` is constant of Activity class. In Activity class you can access directly but in other classes you need to write class name (Activity) also.

Comment: Problem was that the SHA1 wasn't correct on the Google API console, i only set up the SHA1 in the Google play console. @abielita Thank you so much now its working.